# Alternative way to repopulate dataframe with Classification model predictions once you are done testing?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Once you are satisfied with the results of your classification model what alternative can you recommend to mapping your prediction values back to their text form? Classification model was created using scikit.

What I have been doing is just inverting the dictionary and then remapping, see below.

```
d={'Reported Harms':['Fell','Constipation','Surgical Delay'],'Complaint Description':['Patient Fell on face','Could not use bathroom','Medical rep was late']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)

harms=df["Reported Harms"].unique()
harms_dict={value:index for index, value in enumerate(harms)}
results=df["Reported Harms"].map(harms_dict)

df['prediction']=[0,1,2]

inv_map={v:k for k, v in harms_dict.items()}
df["prediction"]=df["prediction"].map(inv_map)
```

Thank you

As some requested to see the model,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
import seaborn as sns

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vect=CountVectorizer(min_df=1)

df=pd.read_excel('Test_data.xlsx',sheet_name='Test')
dff=pd.read_excel('Data_input.xlsx',sheet_name='Complaints')

corpus=df["Complaint Description"]
vectorizer=CountVectorizer(min_df=1)
X=vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()
print(X.shape)

harms=df["Reported Harms"].unique()
harms_dict={value:index for index, value in enumerate(harms)}
results=df["Reported Harms"].map(harms_dict)

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,results,test_size=1,random_state=1,)

clf=MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
clf.score(x_test,y_test)


vec_text=vectorizer.transform(dff["Complaint Description"]).toarray()
ids=dff["Complaint Description"]
dff['prediction']=clf.predict(vec_text)

inv_map={v:k for k, v in harms_dict.items()}
dff["prediction"]=dff["prediction"].map(inv_map)
s=dff['prediction'].value_counts()
sns.barplot(x=s.index,y=s.values)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Legacy_list.xlsx')
dff.to_excel(writer, 'Complaints edit',index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: Can you show how did you train the model? I mean the labels you sent? Scikit-learn automatically handles the conversion of text labels, so in my opinion you did not have to do anything.

Comment: I just added the edits Kumar, I appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the common approaches would be using [sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html):

```
In [15]: from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

In [18]: le = LabelEncoder()

In [19]: df['harms'] = le.fit_transform(df['Reported Harms'])

In [20]: df
Out[20]:
    Complaint Description  Reported Harms  harms
0    Patient Fell on face            Fell      1
1  Could not use bathroom    Constipation      0
2    Medical rep was late  Surgical Delay      2

In [21]: df['decoded'] = le.inverse_transform(df['harms'])
C:\Users\Max\Anaconda3_5.0\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py:151: DeprecationWarning: The truth value of an empty array is ambiguous. R
eturning False, but in future this will result in an error. Use `array.size > 0` to check that an array is not empty.
  if diff:

In [22]: df
Out[22]:
    Complaint Description  Reported Harms  harms         decoded
0    Patient Fell on face            Fell      1            Fell
1  Could not use bathroom    Constipation      0    Constipation
2    Medical rep was late  Surgical Delay      2  Surgical Delay
```

Comment: Can you please give me a few seconds, I need to clear some votes for your awesome answer.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, you are out of shots again? :-D

Comment: Happens every now and then... used to happen more often in the past when I was a lot more active than I am now :D

Answer (score 1):

`pd.factorize` to the rescue:

```
i, j = pd.factorize(df['Reported Harms'])
# Transform
df['encoded'] = i
# Inverse Transform
mapping = dict(zip(j, i))
df["decoded"] = df['encoded'].map(mapping)
```

Answer (score 1):

On your example dataframe, you can just omit the mapping Harms to int parts, which will be automatically handled by Scikit estimators (MultinomialNB in your case).

What you can do is this:

```
d={'Reported Harms':['Fell','Constipation','Surgical Delay'],
   'Complaint Description':['Patient Fell on face','Could not use bathroom','Medical rep was late']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# Convert the text features to numerical
corpus=df["Complaint Description"]
vectorizer=CountVectorizer(min_df=1)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()


# No need to do anything to target classes
results = df["Reported Harms"]

# Now continue with your code

clf=MultinomialNB()

# You can directly do this (or continue with train_test_split as you originally had)
clf.fit(X, results)
```

And now for predictions, when you do `clf.predict()`, the original texts will be returned automatically.

```
d={'Reported Harms':['Surgical Delay', 'Constipation', 'Fell'], 
   'Complaint Description':['Ambulance arrived late', 'Having problems passing urine in bathroom', 'Fell on road',]}
dff = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

vec_text=vectorizer.transform(dff["Complaint Description"]).toarray()
ids=dff["Complaint Description"]
predictions = clf.predict(vec_text)

print(predictions)
# Output: 
          array(['Surgical Delay', 
                 'Constipation', 
                 'Fell'], dtype='|S14')
```

Which you can directly assign to the dataframe without doing any mapping or inverse mapping.

```
dff['prediction'] = predictions
```

The trick here is that the Scikit-estimators automatically convert the supplied text targets into numerical using the LabelEncoder internally as @MaxU suggested in his answer, so you dont need to do that explicitly.

Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: Kumar, "# You can directly do this (or continue with train_test_split as you originally had)
clf.fit(X, results)" for this portion why would you do this as opposed to the test split? I'm trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @Bjc51192 I just did it here, because the sample data is too small. You should definitely go the train test split way. I just wanted to demostrate that you dont need to do any processing on the targets (No mapping and inverse mapping, no label encoding etc) and they will be handled correctly by scikit.